# Slide show using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow, href

I have a slide show using javascript where images display from another server (remote server). i have to display images from another server,problem is when i set "src" property of "Img" html tag, it append my server localhost path at starting as "http:\mysitehost.com\myremoresite.com\image1.jpg" where my image path is "http:\myremotesite.com\image1.jpg".
can any one tell me how to remove my site url "mysitehost.com" from the image path.
below is my javascript.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var width = 283;
var height = 183;
var imgAr1 = new Array();
var rImg1 = new Array();
imgAr1[0] ='<%=url1%>'; // images comes from database with full imagepath like "http:remotesite.com\image.jpg"
imgAr1[1] = '<%= url1%>';
imgAr1[2] = '<%= url2%>';
imgAr1[3] = '<%= url3%>';
imgAr1[4] = '<%= url4%>';
imgAr1[5] = '<%= url5%>'; </script>

//to run slideshow

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//for(var j = 0; j < imgAr1.length; j++)
//{
//      rImg1[j] = new Image();
//        rImg1[j].src =  imgAr1[j];
//        alert(rImg1[j].src);
//}

document.onload = setting();

var slide;
function setting()
{
    slide = document.getElementById('pic');
    slide.setAttribute("src", imgAr1[0] );
    slide.setAttribute("width",width);
    slide.setAttribute("height",height);
    setTimeout("", 5000);
    slideshow();
}

//Image or picture slide show using java script
//slideshow function
var picture = 0;
function slideshow(){
    if(picture < imgAr1.length-1){
        picture=picture+1;
//      slide.src =  imgAr1[picture];
        slide.setAttribute("src", imgAr1[picture]);
        //alert(slide.src);
        setTimeout("slideshow()", 5000);
    }
    else
        {
            picture = -1;
            setTimeout("slideshow()", 5000);
        }
    }
</script>

//ASPX code
<div>
<img id="pic" border="0"  style="z-index: 100" alt="Property Photo" title="Property Photo"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When using an absolute path in the .src attribute, there should be not problems.

Make sure you format the image URL's starting with **http://**myremotesite.com/image.jpg.